# Uploading few bytes of data very frequently(every second)

Tags: java, http, optimization

I have a scenario where I need to send data (very few bytes) to the server in every second. 
This detail is crucial so I need to encrypt it as well.

After digging into it, I think we can use HTTP protocol but in this case HTTP header would be larger than the content itself.

Is there any way we can use this (HTTP protocol) to send data using minimum bandwidth?
Or there can be some other way around beside HTTP?

Comment: Why not just HTTPS? Just "slow feed a stream" (one long-running connection) aka ["Comet"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). Of course this has the overhead of long-running connections, that some servers cannot deal well with (but some can!). The same can be done with HTTP, but HTTPS provides the encryption "for free" -- almost. Of course, this can be done in any "custom" way conceivable, just trying to KISS :)

Comment: @Yahor : B'coz delivery should be guaranteed.

Comment: @pst : In my opinion, HTTP/HTTPS both have overhead of header info(metadata) which in my case is heavier than the data itself.

Comment: @Rites They do -- and especially to *establish* the connection. So if there is only one connection for 1000 samples (for instance), the overhead becomes negligible over the long run. (This results in significantly different traffic than 1000 connections with one sample.) A server supporting Comet -- e.g. request continuations -- such as Jetty should likely be used if there are more than, say, a few hundred feeds.

Comment: @pst : But clients are in millions that means some million connections?

Comment: @Rites If there are that many clients then any naive *single-server* approach is already doomed. Otherwise, see [handling 100,000+ open ("comet") connections](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19456]), which settled on Netty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5519/discussion-between-rites-and-pst)

Comment: Cant see how sending data every second is related to minimum bandwidth  in your case. Does it really matter that your data is sent via minimum transmission units?

Comment: yes. B'coz the client would be running on some mobile device and such a continuous activity could result in heavy data charges

Comment: It doesn't sound like HTTP is the best protocol to use in your case.  Can you use another protocol which supports encryption and uses the same connection each time. BTW: the cost of establishing a new connection each time can be much higher than the cost of sending a header.

Comment: If you are using encryption, you may find that the CPU required is more of a concern than the memory bandwidth you use.  Have you done any test on you system to see how many encrypted connections you can support on one server? (even in theory)

Comment: Do you have to use a standardized protocol?

Answer (score 0):

You could use send a chunked HTTP request to an event-driven HTTP server.

Chunked encoding allows you to make a HTTP request without knowing in advance how much data will be transmitted in the request body. When a new packet is ready you can send a new chunk. On the server side, the arrival of a chunk would fire a new event and can be processed independently. One option for such a server is [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

This solution will also work over HTTPS, if encryption is required.